# Animation is not smooth on first run (when keyboard appears)

Tags: ios, swift2, uianimation

okay so this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007744/animations-during-first-keyboard-appearance-is-sometimes-not-smooth) one , but i followed answer of that question but i didn't worked , so the thing is that i have a Textfield in my view  and i want to move it up when keyboard appears this is my code :

**Notification observer for keyboard's state**

```
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LaunchScreenViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

**function for getting the keyboard's height**

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    duration = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double)
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue()

    keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

}
```

**my animation**

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    self.nextButtonConstraint.constant  = keyboardHeight
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) {
        self.nextButton.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.emailTextField.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

}
```

as you can see that my animation is on `textFieldDidBeginEditing` because  according to similar [question'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007744/animations-during-first-keyboard-appearance-is-sometimes-not-smooth)s answer putting it there will solve the problem  , but still **on first run (when keyboard appears for the first time)** my animation is not smooth

Comment: Is this code within a `UIViewController` subclass? Try calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` instead of calling it on `nextButton` and `emailTextField`.

Comment: @ConnorNeville , thanks for responding man yeah they are inside of `UIViewController` Class , and i tired your suggestion  still no change

Comment: Hmm. Try adding another `NSNotificationCenter` observer for `keyboardDidShow`, and put your animation in there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution may be quite simple.
Try to put all you Code inside of this:

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async{
    // Your Code here
  }
```

This moves the animation to the main Thread, which should speed it up and avoid the unsmooth animation.